# Adding a user to a room connected to a different server with Node, SocketIO and Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am working on writing server-side code in node.js for a swift based iOS application. Currently, the code works when running it on one EC2 instance, but I am working on setting up a network load balancer so that it can more appropriately scale with incoming user traffic. I decided that the easiest way to achieve this is to use the redis adapter. So now, my server.js file includes:

```
const app = new Koa();
const server = http.createServer(app.callback));
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter({ host: 'my-elasticache-redis-endpoint', port: 6379 })
```

Based on the documentation, this seemed like the only step that was necessary from a code standpoint to get redis actually working in the project, but I may be missing something. From an architecture perspective, I enabled sticky sessions on the target group and set up two servers, both running this code. In addition, if I print out the socket io information, I can see that it has adequately connected to the redis endpoint.

The issue is as follows. Lets say I have two people, Person A and Person B, each connected to different servers. The application is supposed to function like so:

Person A adds person B to a socket room. Then the server emits an event to everyone in that room saying that person B has joined, so the front end can respond accordingly.

This is done through the following function:

```
  protected async r_joinRoom(game: GameEntity, player: PlayerEntity): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let socket: any;
      socket = this._io.sockets.connected[player.socket_id];
      if (!socket) {
        socket = this._socket;
      }
      socket.join(`game/${game.id}`, (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(new GameError(`Unable to join the room=${game.id}.\n${err}`));
        }
        res();
      });
    });
  }
```

The premise here is that Person B is a player, and as a player, he has an associated socket id that the server is keeping track of. I believe the issue, however, is that `socket = this._io.sockets.connected[player.socket_id];`  Does not find the connected player, because he is technically connected to a different server. Printing out the socket shows it as null, and if I subsequently have that exact same function run on the server player B is connected to, he joins the room no problem. Therefore, when the emitted events takes place following 'adding' person B to the room, only person A's phone gets the event, and not B. So is this an issue with my Redis setup? Or is there a way to get all the connected clients to any of the servers running the node.js app?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up answering my own question. When you add to the room, you have to do it directly from the adapter. From the documentation, that means I would switch `socket.join...` to

```
io.of('/').adapter.remoteJoin('<my-id>', 'room1', (err) => {
  if (err) { /* unknown id */ }
  // success
});
```

using that remoteJoin function worked off the bat